# Wrap newline in P tag with Regex

Tags: jquery, regex

I am trying to get hold of tinyMCE

tags and since last 2 days I couldn't figure how to solve it. Now am trying to do the following:

I have a text area, that create new lines with \n or \r (probably) so I have to wrap all \n in <*p> tags but there are 2 conditions:

1. If the new line content is already wrapped in P tag it should skip it.
2. The very first P tag should be removed from the content/text line.

Below is what I could do so far:

```
 <textarea id="t"><p>replace P from the very first line until next new line comes</p>

 <p>this should be skipped</p>
 all lines not wrapped in P should be wrapped and the ones already wrapped in P should be skipped

 <p>already wrapped so skip it</p>
 </textarea>
```

the javascript:

```
 var content = $('#t').val().replace(/\n{2,}/g, '<p></p>');
 alert(content);
```

It produces the following result:

```
 <p>replace P from the very first line until next new line comes</p><p></p><p>this should be skipped</p> all lines not wrapped in P should be  wrapped and the ones already wrapped in P should be skipped<p></p><p>already wrapped so skipe it</p>
```

below is jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/s99my37u/

Comment: Try [`var content = $('#t').val().split("\n").slice(1).join("\n").trim().replace(/^(?!<p\b.*<\/p>$).*/m, '<p>$&</p>');`](https://jsfiddle.net/s99my37u/1/)

Comment: thanks @WiktorStribiżew.. however it has completely removed the first line, it should only remove P tags but keep the text line.. secondly the empty blank lines should also be wrapped in<*p><*/p>. here is the fiddle again https://jsfiddle.net/s99my37u/2/ thanks for your time.. regards

Comment: It's clearly a job for an html parser, not for regex.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. I use negative lookahead `(?!)` to find lines that don't start with `<p>` and don't end with `</p>`, and a capturing group to capture the contents of the line `(.*)` and then I replace it with the wrapped captured line `<p>$1</p>` where `$1` denotes the first capturing group.

I also used the multiline flag `m`, so that `^` and `$` match the start and end of a line.

```
var content = $('#t').val().replace(/^(?!<p>)(.*)(?!<\/p>)$/gm, "<p>$1</p>").replace(/<p>(.*)<\/p>/, "$1");
alert(content);
```

Comment: thanks @matt.. it works to some extent, however it doesn't remove the `<p>` tag from the very first element. May be we need to run another regex to remove the occurrence of first `<p>` tag ?

Comment: I'm sorry I missed that requirement. I've edited the answer to include an extra regex to handle removing the `p` tags from the first line.